# How is it that Legolas always has a quiver full of arrows?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium, movie

In the movie version of *The Lord of the Rings*, Legolas is seen many times shooting arrow after arrow, yet he never seems to run out.

For example, after the long battle at the end of *The Fellowship of the Ring*, his quiver is completely filled.

Where are all these arrows coming from? Is it some form of elven magic? If so, it is never explained either in the movie, nor in the book that I can recall.

Comment: He's an elf. 'Nuff said.

Comment: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BottomlessMagazines :)

Comment: For the same reason Rambo never runs out of ammo.

Comment: IDKFA . . . . .

Comment: Quiver of holding?

Comment: The events in the movie happen over many days. The movie is only a few hours long. Not everything happens on-screen. Between the scenes, they have a lot of time to eat, sleep, urinate, and make arrows or scavenge for them after battle.

Comment: Real elvish quiver :)

Comment: Movie unlogic is just unbeatable :-)

Comment: Like a cowboy's six-gun. Reloading on screen is boring.

Answer (score 59):

This might be true in the movie, but certainly not in the books. Twice - in the very battle you mention at the end of Fellowship, and again in the battle of Helm's Deep - he is explicitly described as running out of arrows and having to hunt around for more:

> 'And I,' said Legolas, 'will take all the arrows that I can find, for my quiver is empty.' He searched in the pile on the ground about and found not a few that were undamaged and longer in the shaft than such arrows as the Orcs were accustomed to use.

...

> 'Two!' said Gimli, patting his axe. He had returned to his place on the wall.
>
> 'Two?' said Legolas. 'I have done better, though now I must grope for spent arrows; all mine are gone. Yet I make my tale twenty at the least. But that is only a few leaves in a forest.'

(And yes, he does later go on to use a knife, saying to Gimli: "It has been knife-work up here.")

On a side note, I've always found this set of exchanges between Legolas and Gimli to be faintly disturbing. Although Orcs are "evil", and their enemies in this battle and the wider war, they are still sentient creatures and I would have thought Legolas - as a "good" Elf - would at least show some form of regret at the necessity to slaughter them. But instead, he revels in it and turns it into a competition with his friend. As I say, disturbing.

Comment: Legolas is in fact a "good" elf. he just doesn't live in the 21st century in the western world. He lives in Middle earth in the 3rd age, where "good" and "evil" are easily distinguished, and there is no "grey". There not only it is not disturbing, it is encouraged to count the Orcs you slay.

Comment: But others - even other elves - *do* show that sort of discernment. Remember his own people refused to hurt Gollum, despite everything.

Comment: Gollum wasn't evil, though, just somewhat corrupted due to his long association with the ring. He started out as a hobbit, after all. My impression has been that (almost) every character in the LOTR universe has some innate association with either good or evil, and that although that association may be swayed or even masked, it doesn't get _changed_ outright. Orcs OTOH were a creation of Morgoth (well, sort of, depending on which theory you believe), which I'm pretty sure makes them innately evil.

Comment: Orcs are on a totally different league from Gollum. Gollum is just crazy and schizophrenic, tortured by his desire of the Ring. He still possesses some of his "previous nature", when he was normal, and you can see this when he *starts to change* his behavior thanks to Frodo's kindness. Orcs, on the other hand, in the LoTR story, don't have anything good, they just kill and eat (even among themselves), and leave no space to compassion or other feelings.

Comment: Gollum was pitiable.  An orc isn't pitiable.

Comment: @DanielRoseman: "his own people refused to hurt Gollum, despite everything". Sure, but at the time, Gollum wasn't running towards them in a group of thousands with the intent of killing them as quickly as possible. I don't think you get very far in battle if you stop to shed a tear for each enemy you kill.

Comment: Is it worth pointing out here that orcs are supposed to be corrupted elves. There may be a deeper reason the elves don't consider them worth worrying about. That they want to "de-elvenise" them as much as possible so they don't think of it as killing their own kind?

Comment: Well, Elves don't technically "die," but rather just have their souls sent to the Halls of Mandos to be re-corporated and join their fellow elves.  It's possible that elves are eager to kill orcs in order to liberate their souls and send them off to heal.

Comment: This is dealth with in the Orcs material in Morgoth's Ring: "of necessity, being the fingers of the hand of Morgoth, they must be fought with the utmost severity, they must not be dealt with in their own terms of cruelty and treachery".  So it's OK to kill them without remorse, but it's not OK to torture them.

Comment: Slightly off-topic, but one of the truly good scenes from the old animated version of LOTR has one of the hobbits dreaming of a Middle Earth at peace, including him waving "Hello!" at a passing Orc farmer.

Comment: I suspect Tolkien might have dropped all references to any competition between Legolas and Gimli over who could kill the most orcs if he had heard of a real life example, the "Contest to kill 100 people with a sword" during the Japanese invasion of China.  The more I think about it the creepier it makes Legolas and Gimli seem though there are significant differences.

Comment: *An orc isn't pitiable.*" @Kyralessa  In LOTR Book I Chapter 2 Gandalf says "*As for me, I pity even his slaves*" I would think this includes the orcs, although that is not explicit.

Comment: Orcs do show some elements of a moral code, althogfuh they do not abide by it. In "The Tower of Cirith Ungol" orcks speek contemptuously of leavig a comrad to teh mercy of Shelob. "Regular Elvish trick" they say, arrebuting an immoral action to an enemy. Of course only a few pages later they reveal that they have done the same. Shippey in *Roots and Branches* has a whole essay devoted to this. So they have some sense of the good, even though they do not act on it. It is also not clearly established that orcs come from corrupted elves, that is what some elves thought, but none knew for sure.

Answer (score 16):

In the movie, at the Battle of Helm's Deep, Legolas is seen using two knives instead of his bow and arrow. One might presume that he ran out of arrows. I recall reading in the LOTR wiki that Legolas does indeed run out of arrows, and when that happens he has two knives that he uses as weapons.

From the [*Lord of the Rings* Wiki](https://lotr.fandom.com/wiki/Legolas):

> Legolas carries two weapons with him on his journey with the Fellowship. He sports a slender bow of Mirkwood which he aims with deadly precision. He prefers to pierce his enemies from afar, but he also carries a long knife of unknown make. In Lothlórien he was given a bow of the Galadhrim, stouter than those of the fashion of Mirkwood. Nevertheless he adopts his new bow and makes deadly use of it in the remainder of the War of the Ring. Legolas' skill with the bow is reknowned, perhaps even comparable to that of Beleg Cúthalion.
>
> In the movie adaptation he wields an additional elvish long knife.
>
> <sub>[(Lord of the Rings Fandom page - Legolas:Weapons, archived version from 2012/02/08)](https://lotr.fandom.com/wiki/Legolas)</sub>

Comment: @DVK - Well, you know how I feel about the Wikis. For all I know it's sourced from a monkey's patoot, but let me check the link and see what it says. :)

Comment: @DVK - The sources given for the Legolas page are: *The Lord of the Rings*; *The Book of Lost Tales 2*; The Complete Guide to Middle-earth; Legolas at Tolkien Gateway; Legolas of Mirkwood: Prince Among Equals.